# Select a sample of records distributed over several distinct values

Tags: t-sql

I have a table like:

| Name | Product Code | Payment Type | Member |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Code A | Type 2 | Yes |
| Kat | Code B | Type 2 | Yes |
| Greg | Code C | Type 1 | No |
| David | Code A | Type 1 | Yes |
| Simon | Code A | Type 2 | Yes |

etc. Let's say there's 10k rows in this table.

Across this table, `Name` is the only unique column. I would like to select, for example, 120 rows, but in such a way that the 120 is split as evenly across the possible distinct combinations of `Product Code`, `Payment Type`, and `Member` as possible.

I.e. assuming there are 3 different `Product Code`s, 2 different `Payment Type`s, and 2 different `Member` values (resulting in 12 distinct combinations), the result would be:

- 10 with `Code A`, `Type 1`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code A`, `Type 1`, `No`
- 10 with `Code A`, `Type 2`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code A`, `Type 2`, `No`
- 10 with `Code B`, `Type 1`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code B`, `Type 1`, `No`
- 10 with `Code B`, `Type 2`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code B`, `Type 2`, `No`
- 10 with `Code C`, `Type 1`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code C`, `Type 1`, `No`
- 10 with `Code C`, `Type 2`, `Yes`
- 10 with `Code C`, `Type 2`, `No`

I need to do this without using `WITH` or any @variables or stored procedures etc.

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server? I suggest you add an appropriate tag for greater visibility. What version? If SQL Server, run the command `SELECT @@version` and add the version from the first row to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume the latest version of SQL Server for now.

You can get what you want by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign sequence numbers withing each group of rows having the same `[Product Code], [Payment Type], and [Member]`, sorting by that sequence number, and then selecting the `TOP 120` rows.

This will first select all of the "1" rows across all distinct `[Product Code], [Payment Type], and [Member]` combinations, then all of the "2" rows, etc. This should yield a roughly equal distribution. If one set runs out, the others will fill the difference.

Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT TOP 120 *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY [Product Code], [Payment Type], Member
            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) -- Arbitrary order withing the partition
            ) AS RowNum 
    FROM Data
) D
ORDER BY D.RowNum
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SZcWhmr8).